# What are the right configurations for global method security with Spring Security 3.2.4 for Jersey 2.9 REST services?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-security, jersey, spring-java-config

I'm trying to configure my Jersey REST services to be secured with global method security provided by Spring. I think I'm missing something in the whole picture. Here are pieces of my code:

My security configuration class (I'm trying to do this purely in java code, one of the problems is that most examples are with .xml configurations):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class GlobalMethodSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password")
                .roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

The web security is initialized via:

```
public class WebSecurityInitializer extends
        AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
}
```

(This actually is the same as adding spring filter in the web.xml.)

Methods with annotation `@PreAuthorized("permitAll")` are opened correctly. But when I open an URL which is mapped to a method annotated with `@PreAuthorized("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")`, I get this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed
    org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.doGetSession(Request.java:2934)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getSession(Request.java:2310)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getSession(RequestFacade.java:897)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getSession(RequestFacade.java:909)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:238)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:238)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:238)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache.saveRequest(HttpSessionRequestCache.java:40)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.sendStartAuthentication(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:184)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.handleSpringSecurityException(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:168)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:131)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
```

Comment: this exception can be a symptom, rather than the cause. The request being committed means something is already sent to the browser (client). Can you check with firebug what has been sent?

Answer (score 0):

I did not have luck with extending `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer` either although the following seems to be working for me:

```
public class WebApplicationConfiguration extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        super.onStartup(servletContext);

        servletContext.addFilter("springSecurityFilterChain", DelegatingFilterProxy.class)
                .addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.<DispatcherType>of(DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.ERROR, DispatcherType.ASYNC), false, "/*");
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] {
                GlobalMethodSecurityConfig.class,
                // other java config classes come here
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the exception because "hasRole('ROLE_USER')" in @PreAuthorized("hasRole('ROLE_USER')") annotation of spring security is an expression which is implemented by SecurityExpressionRoot. It by default returns false. 
You might have to add your custom implementation for SecurityExpressionRoot and override 'hasRole' method. For more details refer :  http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html 
I hope this helps !!